# How to replace row values in pyspark?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have a column which name is id and data is like this

+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
|  5 |
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
+----+

I want to replace first 6 row `1,2,3,4,5,6` by `emp` and second 1,2,3,4 by `std`: it is possible?

I tried using replace but I didn't get the desired answer

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried so far?

Comment: MCVE please https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This works:

```
import pandas as pd 

df=pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],'data':[1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4]})
df.loc[:6,'New_COl'] = "emp"
df.loc[6:,'New_COl'] = "std"
```

Comment: thank you but in my condition there is large row with other columns  how can i do this?

Comment: You have to give me more detailed example here...what do u mean by large row and other columns..?

Comment: This is `pandas` instead of `pyspark`: please explain connection between OP and this answer.

Answer (score 3):

For pyspark you can use something like below;

```
>>> from pyspark.sql import Row
>>> import pyspark.sql.functions as F
>>> 
>>> df = sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4]).map(lambda x: Row(x)).toDF(['col'])
>>> df.show()
+---+
|col|
+---+
|  1|
|  2|
|  3|
|  4|
|  5|
|  6|
|  1|
|  2|
|  3|
|  4|
+---+

>>> from pyspark.sql.window import Window
>>> df = df.withColumn("id", F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy(F.lit('A'))))
>>> df = df.withColumn('col', F.when(df.id < 7, 'emp').when(df.id >= 7, 'std')).select('col')
>>> df.show()
+---+
|col|
+---+
|emp|
|emp|
|emp|
|emp|
|emp|
|emp|
|std|
|std|
|std|
|std|
+---+
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer because it supplies an answer with pyspark instead of pandas (+1). Just one note: [`monotonically_increasing_id`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id) does not always provide truely consecutive numbers which could lead to incorrect results here.

Comment: @pansen thank you for the warning. I updated the code and use row_number instead of monotonically_increasing_id. I think it is better